# How can I add OneToMany association to an embedded type?

Tags: jpa, associations, one-to-many

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor //
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Decks{
          
    @EmbeddedId
    private DecksId decksId;     
    
}
```

- 

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DecksId implements Serializable{
    
   private Integer id;
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "decksid",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Deck> deck; 
  
}
```

How can I make a `@OneToMany` association from `DecksId.class` to `Deck.class`? I have tried many things     but none of them has worked. I would like to put many decks into decks.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Deck {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore
    private DecksId decksid;  
    
}
```

In this case I get the following error code: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository' defined`